# Remove value from array on click React.js

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Im building an image slider that maps out and lists an array of image url's.

**I'm trying to save an array of image urls that the user wants to hide from view.**

My plan is to store the array value in a dynamoDB table, then retrieve the array of urls that do not want to be shown, and then filter them out from the mapped images in the slider.

I have an EyeOFF icon shown over the image they click, and that toggles the icon hide true and false with the onClick prop of the image and the icon. --- see `const handleBottomImageClick()`.

My issue is that Im unable to remove the value of the image (img url) from the array thats saved in the state variable `selectedImage`. --- see `const handleTopImageClick()`.

I tried `array.pop()`, and `array.splice()`, but I don't know if those methods would work efficiently for what i'm trying to do.

**Slider Component**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { IonModal, IonContent, IonButton, IonIcon, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol, IonItem, IonLabel } from '@ionic/react';
import { chevronBackOutline, chevronForwardOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';
import { Storage } from "aws-amplify";
import Image from '../components/SliderImages.js';
import FullImage from '../components/LargeSliderImage.js';
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss";
import { chunk } from 'lodash';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import { eyeOffOutline, createSharp, shareSharp } from 'ionicons/icons';




const SliderComponent = (props) => {

    const { job, hideImages } = props;
    const [selectedImage, setSlectedImage] = useState([]);
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    const [activeSlide, setActiveSlide] = useState(false);
    const [initialSlide, setInitialSlide] = useState(0)
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        nav1: null,
        nav2: null
    });
    const slider1 = useRef();
    const slider2 = useRef();

       let imagesToHide = [];

    const SlickArrowLeft = ({ ...props }) => (

        <IonIcon  {...props} type="button" size="large" icon={chevronBackOutline} />

    );

    const SlickArrowRight = ({ ...props }) => (
        <IonIcon {...props} type="button" size="large" icon={chevronForwardOutline} />
    );


    const customStyles = {
        content: {
            top: '50%',
            left: '50%',
            right: 'auto',
            bottom: 'auto',
            marginRight: '-50%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setState({
            nav1: slider1.current,
            nav2: slider2.current
        });
    }, []);

    const {
        nav1,
        nav2
    } = state;

    const settings = {
        infinite: false,
        lazyLoad: "ondemand",
        useCSS: true,
        useTransform: true,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        speed: 500,
        initialSlide: 0,
        autoHeight: false,
        draggable: true,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: <SlickArrowLeft class="prevArrowButton" />,
        nextArrow: <SlickArrowRight class="nextArrowButton" />,

        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1024,
                settings: {
                    lazyLoad: "ondemand",
                    slidesToShow: 4,
                    slidesToScroll: 4,
                    speed: 500,
                    initialSlide: 0,
                    autoHeight: false,

                    arrows: false,
                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 600,
                settings: {
                    lazyLoad: "ondemand",
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    speed: 500,
                    initialSlide: 0,
                    autoHeight: false,

                    arrows: false,

                }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 480,
                settings: {
                    lazyLoad: "ondemand",
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    speed: 500,
                    initialSlide: 0,
                    autoHeight: false,

                    arrows: true,
                    prevArrow: <SlickArrowLeft class="prevArrowButton" />,
                    nextArrow: <SlickArrowRight class="nextArrowButton" />,
                }
            }
        ]
    };

    const viewSettings = {
        infinite: true,
        lazyLoad: "ondemand",
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        speed: 500,
        autoHeight: false,
        focusOnSelect: false,
        initialSlide: initialSlide,
        arrows: true,
        prevArrow: <SlickArrowLeft class="prevArrowButton" />,
        nextArrow: <SlickArrowRight class="nextArrowButton" />,

    }


    useEffect(() => {
        async function onLoad() {

            try {
                const downloadedImage = await getImage(job);
                setImages(downloadedImage);
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        onLoad();
    }, [job]);


    async function getImage(jobID) {
        const imageURL = await Storage.list(`${jobID}/completed/`);
        let imagesToDownload = imageURL
        let imagesAsArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < imagesToDownload.length; i++) {
            const imagesDownloaded = await getURLFromS3(imagesToDownload[i]);
            imagesAsArray.push(imagesDownloaded)
        }
        return imagesAsArray
    }

    async function getURLFromS3(fileToDownload) {
        const result = await Storage.get(fileToDownload.key)
        return result;
    }


    const handleBottomImageClick = function (index, image2) {
        if (hideImages) {
            if (selectedImage[image2]) {
                setSlectedImage({ ...selectedImage, [image2]: false })
            } else {
                setSlectedImage({ ...selectedImage, [image2]: !selectedImage[image2] })
            }

        } else {

            setShowModal(true)
            const i = index + index + 1
            setInitialSlide(i)

        }

    }

    const handleTopImageClick = function (index, image1) {
        if (hideImages) {
            if (selectedImage[image1]) {
                const arr = [selectedImage]
                arr.splice(selectedImage[image1])
                setSlectedImage(arr)
            } else {
                setSlectedImage({ ...selectedImage, [image1]: !selectedImage[image1]})
            }
        } else {
            setShowModal(true)
            const i = index + index
            setInitialSlide(i)
        }
    }


    return (
        <>
            {hideImages ? (

                <div className="ion-padding" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <IonLabel position="stacked"> Select the images you want to hide from the customer view. Tap finished when done. </IonLabel>
                    <br /><br />
                    <div style={{ justifyContent: 'center', display: "flex" }}>
                        <IonButton onClick={() => console.log(selectedImage)} size="small">
                            Finished
                    </IonButton>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                </div>

            ) : (
                    null
                )}
            <div style={{ justifyContent: 'center', display: "flex" }}>

                <Slider className="image-slider-frame" asNavFor={nav1} ref={slider => (slider1.current = slider)} {...settings}>
                    {chunk(images, 2).map(([image1, image2], i) =>

                        <ul className="listing-image-slidee" key={i}>

                            <div>
                                <li className="listing-image-pairs">
                                    <img onClick={() => {handleTopImageClick(i, image1);} } height="206px" width="272px" className="img" src={image1} />
                                    <IonIcon onClick={() => handleTopImageClick(i, image1)} className="image-hide" key={image1} size="large" hidden={selectedImage[image1] ? false : true} icon={eyeOffOutline} />
                                </li>
                            </div>

                            <div >
                                {image2 && <li className="listing-image-pairs">
                                    <img onClick={() => handleBottomImageClick(i, image2)} height="206px" width="272px" className="img" src={image2} />
                                    <IonIcon className="image-hide" key={image2} size="large" onClick={() => handleBottomImageClick(i, image2)} hidden={selectedImage[image2] ? false : true} icon={eyeOffOutline} />
                                </li>}
                            </div>

                        </ul>

                    )}
                </Slider>

            </div>
            <div>

                <Modal ariaHideApp={false} className="Modal" isOpen={showModal}>
                    <IonGrid>
                        <IonRow clasName="ion-no-padding" style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }} >
                            <IonCol sizeXs="13" sizeSm="13" sizeMd="9" sizeLg="7" sizeXl="7" >
                                <Slider style={{ maxHeight: "768px" }} asNavFor={nav2} ref={slider => (slider2.current = slider)}  {...viewSettings}>
                                    {(images).map((image, i) =>
                                        <div>
                                            <br />
                                            <img src={image} />
                                        </div>

                                    )}
                                </Slider>
                                <br/>
                                <IonItem lines="none">
                                    <IonButton size="small" color="secondary" slot="end" onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>close</IonButton>
                                </IonItem>
                            </IonCol>
                        </IonRow>
                    </IonGrid>
                </Modal>

            </div>
        </>
    )
}
export default SliderComponent;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use `splice` or `pop` to remove item from an array, because it mutates react state directly. You may use the `filter` function to remove that item. The filter function returns a new array without modifying the original one.

```
const newArr = selectedImage.filter(item => item !== image1);
setSelectedImage(newArr);
```

Comment: This will not work because ```selectedImage``` is an object with keys. The key is the image url, and the value is either true or false. I want to return only the keys that are === to true.

Comment: im setting the state ```setSelectedImage({ ...selectedImage, [image2]: false }) ``` or ```setSelectedImage({ ...selectedImage, [image2]: true })```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you must initialize `selectedImage` with `object` and not an array as that is what you expect it to be later

Second, assuming its an object, you won't use `splice` on it. You would either delete the key or make it false.

In any case you must make sure you are cloning the object before updating in state

```
const [selectedImage, setSlectedImage] = useState({}); // Initialize object
...
const handleTopImageClick = function (index, image1) {
    if (hideImages) {
        if (selectedImage[image1]) {
            setSlectedImage({...selectedImage, [image1]: false}); // hide image
        } else {
            setSlectedImage({ ...selectedImage, [image1]: true}); // show
        }
    } else {
        setShowModal(true)
        const i = index + index
        setInitialSlide(i)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setSelectedImage(prevImages => {
  const index = prevImages.indexOf(image1);
  return [...prevImages.slice(0, index), ...prevImages.slice(index+1)];
});
```

The idea is, find the index of the element in the list. 
When you know its position, you can return a new array, where you spread the existing one from start to index, and then from index + 1 to the end. This will not mutate the existing state-objekt.

Also, when setting state based on previous state, it is safest to use the callback function of the state-set property. The get'er that comes from useState is not guaranteed to be the latest and greatest when the change happens.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: thanks for your reply to my question. Unfortunately this is not working though. Its throwing an error, ```prevIndex.indexOf() is not a function```.  Im also chunking the array into two parts because I am listing the images in pairs which causes the images to share an index per two images, so I had to come up with an equation for the top image click and bottom image click to capture the index from the original array, so that when they click an image, it pops up in a modal with the initial slide as the one they clicked.

Comment: should be prevImages, not prevIndex ;) If this is an array, it should have the indexOf function available.

Answer (score 0):

let us assume we have an array `images` containing all the images. And let `hiddenImages` be the array which will hold all the images that we want to hide on click. Then the function `hideImage()` can be called with the parameter `imageId` which can be triggered `onClick` of the button. Then the function will filter out the image with the corresponding image id and add it to the hiddenImages array, also it will remove the image from the `images` array by splicing the array at the index of the selected image, as shown below.

```js
function Carousel(props) {
  let images = [
    {
      id: 321,
      url: "",
    },
    {
      id: 322,
      url: "",
    },
  ];

  let hiddenImages = [];

  let hideImage = (imageId) => {
    hiddenImages = [
      ...hiddenImages,
      ...images.filter((item) => item.id == imageId),
    ];
    let index;
    images.map((image) => {
      if (image.id == imageId) {
        index = images.indexOf(image);
        return;
      }
    });
    images.splice(index, 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {images && images.length
        ? images.map((image, key) => {
            return (
              <img key={key} src={image.url} onClick={hideImage(image.id)} />
            );
          })
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: I think you made an unnecessary use of '...' as filter already return an new array.